# Can you draw a binary tree given its pre-order binary sequence/ordering?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, huffman-code

Binary trees (and hence ordered forests) can be represented as binary strings. The binary string is obtained by traversing a binary tree in preorder, recording a 1 for every node and a 0 for every empty subtree (null link).

This means that if I'm given a binary tree, I can do a preorder traversal and produce a binary sequence representation.

Is the opposite also possible? If I'm given this binary sequence `11011000101101010001`, can I draw the binary tree?

Comment: So if a tree has a single node, would its representation be `100`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.

Label the internal nodes as `a` and the external ones as `b`; of course you can assume `a` as `0` and `b` as `1` (and vice-versa). But I think is easier to distinguish letters than numbers (although this matter of "taste").

If you don't know what are the "external nodes", then you can assume that they are the `NULL` pointers.

Now, the preorder traversal of any tree labeled as I have said forms a word belonging to Lukasiewicz language. It could be shown that this word is unique. That is, for any pair of trees `t1` and `t2`, `code(t1) != code(t2)`; always! In addition (and this should have been the reason for which you are concerned to Huffman encoding), the Lukasiewicz language is prefix.

For example, for the tree

[image]

Its preorder traversal is `aaaabbabbaabbbababb` or `000011011001110111`

I leave to you the code for generating a code; it is a preorder traversal. If you are interested in reversing it, that is, to get the tree given the code, then this pseudo-code, which tries to answer your question, would do it:

```
Node * code_to_tree(char *& code)
{
  if (*code++ == 'b')
    return nullptr;

  Node * p = new Node;
  LLINK(p) = code_to_tree(code);
  RLINK(p) = code_to_tree(code);

  return p;
}
```

In a real implementation, you would read bits.

The routine above assumes that the code is right; that is, it was generated from a binary tree. Note that not all words composed by `a`'s and `b`'s belong to the Lukasiewicz language. But some showable rules could be applied on them.

First, the number of `b`'s must be exactly the number of `a`'s plus one. Second, if each `a` weights one (1) and each `b` weights minus one (-1), then, at the exception of last `b`, the addition through all the word for each letter never can be smaller than zero. Only at the end of the word the addition will be `-1`. If the word does not satisfy this condition, then you can assume that it is invalid.

Comment: Nicely done. Note, however, that according to this solution (which, by the way, I think is correct), the OP's example string, `11011000101101010001` is not a valid tree.

Answer (score 2):

Sure!

Create a binary tree, assign a number to each element

```
        0
   1----|-----2
 3-|-4     5--|--6
7|8 9|10 11|12 13|14
...
```

These are your indices.

Define a size for your node data and you can get the information for a node in the tree at `data_size * index`

This is commonly how heaps are represented.

There are plenty of ways to represent a binary tree as a string. However, because there are so many ways you have to agree on a particular representation before you can move forward. What I've mentioned above is just one way to represent a binary tree, and it may not be the standard that you all are using.